# How can I direct-message a Facebook user from my app?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Well, thats exactly what i would like to know. Is there any possibility to send a direct message? I came to know that facebook has deprecated sending messages to users inbox but there's gotta be way. We could ask for 'email' extended permission to email them but we wanna send to their facebook inbox only.

We would like to send special offers based on their interests. Can some one please tell me how to do this? or help me in find a way around?

Comment: as you already mentioned they disabled the functions to send notifications to the users to prevent spam, erm, special offers the way you want to: http://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/365

Comment: So there's no way? But how come i'm getting messages to my inbox from other apps/pages?

Answer (score 7):

You can't do it. Any of the applications that do this 1) either have some special deal with Facebook or 2) are doing it in a way that is not sanctioned. The new way to do this is to ask for the users email and just email them directly.

Answer (score 3):

you can send a message to any user from your app, but the current logged-in
user must approve it manually:

> From Facebook api > Dialogs › Send Dialog

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/send/

Comment: Doesn't the message come from the user of the app and not from the "app"?